# Sending the bearer token with axios

Tags: reactjs, rest, token, axios, access-token

In my react app i am using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to perform the REST api requests.

But it's unable to send the *Authorization* header with the request.

Here is my code:

```
tokenPayload() {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + validToken()
    }
  }
  Axios.post( 
      'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads',
      config
    )
    .then( ( response ) => {
      console.log( response )
    } )
    .catch()
}
```

Here the `validToken()` method would simply return the token from browser storage.

All requests are having a 500 error response saying that

> The token could not be parsed from the request

from the back-end.

How to send the authorization header with each requests? Would you recommend any other module with react?

Comment: I don't think its an `axios` issue at all. check your `validToken()` function, it returning somthing that your server does not understand.

Comment: I double checked the function and also used the token string here instead of the function,, still the same

Answer (score 389):

```
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};

const bodyParameters = {
   key: "value"
};

Axios.post( 
  'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads',
  bodyParameters,
  config
).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

The first parameter is the URL.
The second is the JSON body that will be sent along your request.
The third parameter are the headers (among other things). Which is JSON as well.

Comment: You missed a space between bearer  and token - then it will work.

Comment: Doctor's post: "key: "value" has a quote that should be removed... But fixing that did get the auth to work for my react-native app.

Comment: @mediaguru Thx for the comment. I fixed it (I suppose) ! The quote must have been introduce by someone editing the answer...

Comment: `Bearer` should be used with capital B, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Alizadeh118 It seems to be working with and without any capital letters :-)

Comment: @Alizadeh118 Yes, according to the HTTP spec. But many api's don't insist on the correct capitalization.

Comment: For some `API's` you might need to add `/` at the end of the endpoint. For example, instead of `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads` should be `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads/`.

Comment: I would like to add the definition of the axios post request to follow up correctly each call https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/e9965bfafc82d8b42765705061b9ebe2d5532493/index.d.ts#L151

Comment: Anyone else upvoting for the clever usage of console.log as param?

Comment: @NicolasDurán Not me for one... I hate it when people just edit my answers. I don't even get notified. Even if the console.log() is better i didn't test it. So I can't vouch for the quality anymore.

Answer (score 177):

Here is a unique way of setting Authorization token in axios. Setting configuration to every axios call is not a good idea and you can change the default Authorization token by:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:1010/'
axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`}
export default axios;
```

Some API require bearer to be written as Bearer, so you can do:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}
```

Now you don't need to set configuration to every API call. Now Authorization token is set to every axios call.

Comment: `Bearer` needs to be capitalised for some APIs (I discovered the hard way).

Comment: This should be accepted answer. This is better approach.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher not if yo use different servers

Comment: @Musculaa the question is not about different servers .

Comment: for loading token from a function or local storage we need interceptors

Comment: The spec says to always use "Bearer" with a capitol B. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750

Comment: Here It is keeping the token in an axios header. is this a secure way of storing the token ?

Comment: @tnishada you can try cookie based authentication.

Answer (score 61):

You can create config once and use it everywhere.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
});

instance.get('/path')
.then(response => {
    return response.data;
})
```

Comment: Where is the value of token passed from in this example?  For my application, the token would be passed back to the api either in the header or body after a successful login.

Comment: its here `headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}`

Comment: How to pass data if it is an POST request

Comment: For those who are wondering from where the value of token can be passed, here is es6 syntax - ```const instance = (token) => axios.create({
  baseURL: `${config.API_URL}`,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers :{ 'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
})```

Comment: instance.get('/path')
.then(response => {
    return response.data;
})

What is path ??

Comment: @ZebraCoder `path` in this context is whatever you'd normally put after your base URL `https://example.com/api/`, also known as the endpoint.

Answer (score 35):

By using Axios interceptor:

```
const service = axios.create({
  timeout: 20000 // request timeout
});

// request interceptor

service.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    // Do something before request is sent

    config.headers["Authorization"] = "bearer " + getToken();
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: **Is this the community standard for configuring the headers with axios?**

Comment: @5ervant I had a really ugly time using this approach. It was a lot of pain and I so don't recommend it.

Comment: @ankush981 what is so bad about this approach and which one do u recommend?

Comment: @NenadKaevik There's a particular use case I was trying to cover (response interception): letting the user know when the server says 403 in response. People generally put the token verification step during component load, but suppose your token was invalidated a few seconds after it was verified (for whatever reason). Now when the person clicks a button, I'd like them to know they've been signed out. It's hard to do this using interceptors as they add global behavior. I got into a reload loop because the request interceptor would always add the token and the response interceptor would redirect

Comment: @NenadKaevik So, maybe the flow was hard to achieve or I was using the wrong approach, but since then I kind of started hating interceptors.

Comment: @ankush981 You are damn right about this... Thanks for the explanation brudda :)

Comment: i think using `interceptor` is the standard way to go because when you use `common` headers, the headers are only computed once when the axios is initialized and if your token is changed after initializing axios, axios won't update its headers.

Answer (score 33):

The second parameter of `axios.post` is `data` (not `config`). `config` is the third parameter. Please see this for details: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axiosposturl-data-config

Answer (score 18):

If you want to some data after passing token in header so that try this code

```
const api = 'your api'; 
const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
const token = user.data.id; /*take only token and save in token variable*/
axios.get(api , { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} })
.then(res => {
console.log(res.data);
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 12):

**Just in case someone faced the same issue.**

The issue here is when passing the header without data, the header's configuration will be in the payload data, So I needed to pass null instead of data then set the header's configuration.

```
const config = {
         headers: {
             "Content-type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${Cookies.get("jwt")}`,
         },
    };    
axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`, null, config)
```

Comment: I do not know why but for me only axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`, config) worked! Adding the null ends in 401

Answer (score 10):

This works and I need to set the token only once in my `app.js`:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
};
```

Then I can make requests in my components without setting the header again.

`"axios": "^0.19.0",`

Comment: I don't know why but with this way it's doesn't work on Safari on iOS device :(

Comment: nice simple method for me

Answer (score 6):

I use a separate file to init axios instance and at the same time, I add intercepters to it. Then in each call, the intercepter will add the token to the request header for me.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getToken } from '../hooks/useToken';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = getToken();
    const auth = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Here is how I use it in the service file.

```
import { CancelToken } from 'axios';
import { ToolResponse } from '../types/Tool';
import axiosInstance from './axios';

export const getTools = (cancelToken: CancelToken): Promise<ToolResponse> => {
  return axiosInstance.get('tool', { cancelToken });
};
```

Comment: Clear solution. can you give ToolResponse file example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

// usetoken is hook i mad it

```
export const useToken = () => {
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token || ''
}
const token = useToken();



const axiosIntance = axios.create({
    baseURL: api,
    headers: {
        'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`
    }
});

axiosIntance.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    if(token){
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return req;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending a post request with empty data remember to always set the second parameter to either empty object or empty string just as in the example below. e.g: axios.post('your-end-point-url-here', '', config)

if you don't set it axios will assume that whatever you are passing as the second parameter is a formData

```
const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${storage.getToken()}` }
    };
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads', {}, config)
      .then(({ data: isData }) => {
        console.log(isData);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You must mention the 2nd parameter **body** for the post request even if it is empty, try this :

```
tokenPayload() {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + validToken()
    }
  }
  Axios.post( 
      'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads',
      // empty body
      {},
      config
    )
    .then( (response) => {
      console.log(response)
    } )
    .catch()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring the header like this:

`const headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain", "x-access-token": token}`

Answer (score 0):

try one of these✅:

pass an empty object/payload as a **second parameter** to Axios.post

```
axios.post(
'/api/user/get-user-info-by-id',  //first paramater
{},                               //pass empty object to second paramater
{
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+ localStorage.getItem("token"),
        }
      })
```

or pass a null

```
axios.post('/api/user/get-user-info-by-id',null, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+ localStorage.getItem("token"),
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I used like this -
**Get API**

```
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `api`,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        const data = res?.data;
        if (data?.isSuccess) {
         console.log("data>>>>>>",data)
        } else {
          console.log(data?.errorMessage);
        }
      });
```

**Post API**

```
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "api",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      data: {
        name: "name",
        email: "email",
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
     if (data?.isSuccess) {
         console.log("data>>>>>>",data)
        } else {
          console.log(data?.errorMessage);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the config object correctly to Axios. Config object should be passed as the third argument to Axios.post(), and data as the second argument.

```
tokenPayload() {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + validToken()
    }
  };

  Axios.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/get_token_payloads',
    {}, // pass an empty object as data if you don't have any data to send
    config
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`axios` by itself comes with two useful "methods" the `interceptors` that are none but middlewares between the request and the response. so if on each request you want to send the token. Use the `interceptor.request`.

I made apackage that helps you out:

```sh
$ npm i axios-es6-class
```

Now you can use axios as class

```js
export class UserApi extends Api {
    constructor (config) {
        super(config);

        // this middleware is been called right before the http request is made.
        this.interceptors.request.use(param => {
            return {
                ...param,
                defaults: {
                    headers: {
                        ...param.headers,
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`
                    },
                }
            }
        });

      this.login = this.login.bind(this);
      this.getSome = this.getSome.bind(this);
   }

   login (credentials) {
      return this.post("/end-point", {...credentials})
      .then(response => this.setToken(response.data))
      .catch(this.error);
   }


   getSome () {
      return this.get("/end-point")
      .then(this.success)
      .catch(this.error);
   }
}
```

I mean the implementation of the `middleware` depends on you, or if you prefer to create your own `axios-es6-class`
https://medium.com/@enetoOlveda/how-to-use-axios-typescript-like-a-pro-7c882f71e34a
it is the medium post where it came from

Answer (score -2):

there are a lot of good solution but I use this

```js
let token=localStorage.getItem("token");

var myAxios=axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:5001',
  timeout: 700,
  headers: {'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`}
});

export default myAxios;
```

then i import myaxios to my file and

```js
myAxios.get("sth")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use interceptors in axios:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

More on that you can find here: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors