# How to use Laravel Passport access tokens

Tags: axios, laravel-passport

First let me describe the problem I want to solve. I have a Laravel backend project that I want to tranform into an API, and it looked like Laravel Passport was perfect for this. Therefore, I installed Laravel Passport into my project.

I have a client app which needs to use this API using axios. What I want to do is to make a post request with my username and password to the API to get an [access token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#issuing-access-tokens), and then use this access token to get or post relevant data. The access token is created by the following code

```
public function login()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json($success['token']);
        // return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

and my app stores the access token.  Am I correct in thinking that my app can now use this access token to gain access to the data of the user I made the login with? If so, how would I do that? I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios), but I could not make it work.

I will gladly post more code if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help. when i store the access token on my frontend app i also attach the header

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token.data.access_token
```

all your axios request will use this header.

getting user detail

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```