# Laravel Passport clients has user_id null

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am making a react app that uses a laravel passport backend to get and post data from a database. I have full control over the app code and the laravel backend code.

I can make an access token just fine, either using a client, or simply by issuing a user to make one, but I can't use this access token to access data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios). Sending such a request with the generated access token gives me a 401 every time.

I believe My problem is when making clients. I have 2 clients (made when running php artisan passport:install), but they both have user_id=null. I'm assuming this should be set some integer when a user uses the client to for example issue an access token? But, it doesn't.

So, does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Below I am posting my user model, and the migration files users and oath_clients. Feel free to ask for more code if needed!

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'api_token', 'redcap_token', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];     
}
```

Users migration:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

Oauth migrations

```
class CreateOauthClientsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('secret', 100);
        $table->text('redirect');
        $table->boolean('personal_access_client');
        $table->boolean('password_client');
        $table->boolean('revoked');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('oauth_clients');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to me you need to reference the relationship that a User `hasOne` OAuth and a OAuth `belongsTo` a User. Add this to your oauth_clients migration:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Then include the necessary relationships in the Models. Hope this helps!

```
// User's Table
public function oauth()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OAuth::class, 'user_id');
}

// OAuth Table
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: This sounds exactly what I was hoping for! I have two followup questions, if you don't mind.

Comment: Followup questions:

Passport makes everything really neat, and really hidden, so I don't even know where I should to find the Oath class. By extension, I don't know how to access the OAuth models.  

Sorry if I'm being stupid here, but I'm still new to Laravel/Passport, and the slickness of the framework confuses me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Qauth migration where the user_id can be null

```
$table->integer('user_id')->index()->nullable();
```

either you pass this when you add the clients using for example uuid or set this as increment..

Comment: Aha. But shouldn't this be tied to the user using the client, or am I misunderstanding what this does?