# Where should I pass the Bearer Authentication Token in a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, authentication, token

I got a Bearer Token and I don't know what to do with it. It's a React Project and I'm using Axios to get data from the API. My question is where does this Token go? Should I put it everytime I use Axios.get or I can store it somewhere?

Comment: I tried using : 
axios.get(API_URL, { headers: { "Authorization" : client_token }})
But I get an Error: Request failed with status code 405

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be nice to have some context, in order to better help: where did you find this token? BTW error 405 means that you tried the wrong http method: probably GET instead of POST, or similar error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put in Authorization headers in every request. Refer to this answer 
[Sending the bearer token with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios)

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = "";

let body= {}

let header= {
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + yourToken}
};

axios.post(url, body, header)
 .then(res => {
   console.log(res)
 }).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
 });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way you can add bearer authentication token to your axios instance using this pattren

```
 let api = axios.create({
      baseURL: YOUR_BASE_urL,
      timeout: 7000,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
```

best way consider is JWT authentication token shoud be stored in LocalStorage
and write method to get token from localStorage and assign it axios instance

```
function addToken() {
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = !!localStorage.getItem('jwt') ? `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwt')}` : '';
}
```

now you have axios instance and method with which you can get Token from localStorage and assign to axios instance

one step is left

You just need to execute this method before making request to axios 
execute function before creating api call

```
addToken()
```

Or

You can prefer adding token to you axios instance directly

```
 let api = axios.create({
          baseURL: YOUR_BASE_urL,
          timeout: 7000,
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "bearer " + token
          }
        });
```