# Not able to get data from AXIOS inside useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, get

I'm trying to GET data from *axios* inside *useEffect()* in React.
I tested the backend it's working fine, but in frontend I'm getting an error **401 (Unauthorized)**

**React Code:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function UpdateItem({ match, history }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();

...

useEffect(() => {
    const fetching = async () => {
      console.log("I'm there !!!");    //OUTPUT: I'm there !!!

      const { data } = await axios.get(`/items/${match.params.id}`);

      console.log("data from useEffect: ", data);     //OUTPUT: 

      setTitle(data.title);
      setDescription(data.description);
      };

    fetching();

    console.log("Title: ", title);                //OUTPUT: Title: undefined
    console.log("Description: ", description);    //OUTPUT: Description:  undefined
    console.log("I'm here !!!");                  //OUTPUT: I'm here !!!
  }, [match.params.id]);

...  
}
```

**Backend Code:**

**server.js**

```
app.use("/items", itemRoutes);
```

**itemRoutes.js**

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

router.route("/:id").get(
   asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
     const wantedItem = await Item.findById(req.params.id);
     if (wantedItem) {
       res.json(wantedItem);
     } else {
       res.status(404).json({ message: "Requested item is not found!" });
     }

     res.json(wantedItem);
   });
)
```

and the error I'm getting:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/items/614dbaea5338fa8622d8e3df 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I'll be glad if anyone can help me to figure out the mistake

Comment: that means the endpoint is protected are you sure you dont need some access token to access that end point

Comment: Aside from the 401 error, your `console.log` statements will never show the data, because A) it **hasn't been retrieved yet** when you call them, and B) it wouldn't be in those variables anyway (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state). When you set the state, your component function will get called again, and in that new call you'll get back the state from `useState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not directly access the data in the `useEffect` method when you set it using the hooks.

Example :

```
  useEffect(() => {
      setTitle("This is title");
      console.log("Title: ", title);                //OUTPUT: Title: undefined
  }, [match.params.id]);
```

You can add a dependency and check it when the `title` value is changed

```
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Title: ", title);                //OUTPUT: This is title
  }, [title]);
```

Edit the answer

If API's throw the 401 means `Unauthorized`. You need to pass `authentication token` in your API call for validation of the API request from the `backend` side.

Here you can check how to pass `token` in API calls.
[Sending the bearer token with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios)

Comment: The main problem in the question is a bit buried, but it's a 401 from the server, not the React state issue. If it **were** the React state issue, the question would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state and not need its own answers.

Comment: Axios treats 401 as an error 
It won't allow you to parse the body so you will have to judge according to status code

Comment: Indeed! it is solved by passing an authentication token to my endpoint to ensure validation... Thanks!