# How to correctly send the CSRF token with Axios, React and Laravel 9. Request failed with status code 419

Tags: reactjs, axios, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I'm using React, Inertia, Breeze and Laravel 9. When sending a request to the server with Axios, I get the following error: `{message: 'Request failed with status code 419', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'.

My code is the following (React):

```
const handleLogout = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
      console.log(token);
      axios.post('logout', { name: 'John Doe' }, {
          headers: {
          'content-type': 'text/json',
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
          }
      }
      );
    };
```

and in my HTML I have:

```
            {{-- CSRF Token --}}
        <meta name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

It correctly prints the token in console.log but throws me the error. Something when passing the token does not work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios